# How to make a controller scope inside another one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller named `status` with a lots of methods like `first`, `second` and so on and so far.

So, I have a `routes.rb` file looks like this:

```
scope 'status', controller: :status do
  get 'first'
  get 'second'
  # and so on
end
```

I also have a path that should looks like '/status/states':

```
scope :status do
  resources :states
end
```

How can I merge these scopes to one for using DRY & clean code?

Answer (score 3):

```
  resource :status, only: [], controller: :status do
    resources :states
    collection do
      get 'first'
      get 'second'
      get 'third'
    end
  end
```

Will give you this:

```
       status_states GET    /status/states(.:format)          states#index
                     POST   /status/states(.:format)          states#create
    new_status_state GET    /status/states/new(.:format)      states#new
   edit_status_state GET    /status/states/:id/edit(.:format) states#edit
        status_state GET    /status/states/:id(.:format)      states#show
                     PATCH  /status/states/:id(.:format)      states#update
                     PUT    /status/states/:id(.:format)      states#update
                     DELETE /status/states/:id(.:format)      states#destroy
        first_status GET    /status/first(.:format)           status#first
       second_status GET    /status/second(.:format)          status#second
        third_status GET    /status/third(.:format)           status#third
```